# Reverse Proxy Secruity Risks

Tags: wordpress, apache, security, nginx, reverse-proxy

Situation:

Consider the site: example.com, hosted at web server A.

A WordPress blog is to be installed on a different web server, B.

In order to route a WordPress installation to a subdirectory on the main site, e.g. example.com/blog/, we used a reverse proxy.

We have done this a number of times for other clients (SEO reasons) to keep content within the domain. The main reason we never install WordPress in a subdirectory is for security purposes.

Question:

We know that there are some security risks with reverse proxies e.g. This [Original Post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51056/does-reverse-proxy-between-two-web-servers-impact-security-of-both) - how do we overcome them?

What also would be best practice to reduce security risks when use reverse proxies in this way?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I don't consider that the utilisation of a proxy is a security threat.

For the "Same-Origin Policy": it's true, if server B is hacked you can (perhaps) do some mess on server A, but basically if you have a server hacked it's your fault not the proxy one!

On the other hand, I fully understand what Tom Leek wanted to tell, if one website is hacked you don't want the other to have repercussion too.
Then to make mylittlesubdomain.mywebsite.com is a solution because you will have no link between server A and B.
I though that search engine as google took care of subdomains quite well, many big websites just do the blog.website.com